# Convert Categorical codes to Categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a dataframe:

```
ga_deviceCategory_codes ga_channelgrouping_codes    ga_sourceMedium_codes   
        1.0                         6.0                      9.0
        1.0                         6.0                      9.0
```

Which I have converted into categorical codes from categorical values using :

```
data['ga_deviceCategory_codes'] = data['ga_deviceCategory'].astype('category').cat.codes
data['ga_channelgrouping_codes'] = data['ga_channelgrouping'].astype('category').cat.codes
data['ga_sourceMedium_codes'] = data['ga_sourceMedium'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

How do I get back to the original categorical values now from the above codes?

Comment: You may want to look at dummies variable :-)

Comment: @Wen- Can I not get the original values from what I have done so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Category mappings are stored internally by Pandas, but not as a regular Python dictionary. You can create such a dictionary yourself to map backwards:

```
df['mycol'] = df['mycol'].astype('category')
d = dict(enumerate(df['mycol'].cat.categories))
```

Then map backwards:

```
df['mycol_codes'] = df['mycol'].cat.codes
df['mycol_reversed'] = df['mycol_codes'].map(d)
```

Be careful with this method. Make sure you create the dictionary straight after you convert to categories. When concatenating dataframes with categorical series, you may find the mapping changes.

Comment: The best solution! The greatest @jpp. Thanks alot. Worked like a magic :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do this as follow:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('category')
my_list = df['col'].cat.codes
my_values = df['col'].tolist()
result= dict(zip(my_list,my_values))
```

first convert your target columns to 'category' type, and then do label encoding on it using .cat.codes. then in line 3 of code, a list of target column real values is created, and in line 4 by zip, each values achived by cat.codes and related real values are consider as an element of a dict.

Comment: It would be better to add some explanation as to how your code works, and how it is better than other answers.

Answer (score 0):

not 100% on what you are asking, but have you tried e.g.:

`data['ga_sourceMedium_codes'].cat.categories`

Comment: Getting an error- `AttributeError: Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype` @Andrew

Comment: you'll have to provide more information to your question if you want a better answer. It is hard for SO users to understand what you are asking. do your categorical variables have only one category each? are they all integers? what did they look like beforehand? etc. The more info you provide the more you can be helped

Comment: No there are ofcourse not one category. They are all some text values - like `device name`, `channel name`, `media names` etc. I have converted them to numeric using the above described procedure to fit into my deep learning model. Now after I am done with my model development and training, I want to show the real values and not the numerical values. I hope this makes some sense now :)

Comment: a bit more, but not fully. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve check this link to see what the users on this site expect. There is a bit of a learning curve to asking questions the right way, but once you edit your question for clarity and adhere to the standards in this link, people will be more than willing to help.